# Two identical subgraphs with same nodes overlapping to each other - tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to link subA->subB where subA and subB have all components exactly the same. When I draw it, the two subgraphs overlapping with each other. Any idea?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs, graphdrawing, positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning,calc}
\usegdlibrary {layered,force, circular, trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, auto]
  \graph [layered layout, sibling distance=15mm, grow'=right] {
  subA [draw, circle] // [tree layout] {a -> {1,2};};
  subB [draw, circle] // [tree layout] {a -> {1,2};};

  subA -> subB
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I got:

[image]

but I need to separate subA and subB and keep their nodes as {a, 1, 2}, yes, their nodes are exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

Notice the [`fresh nodes` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/fresh:nodes) which you can also give only to a sublayout.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary {layered, trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, auto]
\graph [layered layout, sibling distance=15mm, grow'=right, fresh nodes] {
  subA [draw, circle] // [tree layout] {a -> {1, 2};};
  subB [draw, circle] // [tree layout] {a -> {1, 2};};
  subA -> subB
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

If you find yourself needing a specifiy subgraph repeatedly, you can declare your own graph with the [`declare` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/declare).
At the end of that section, the manual also offers another solution to you problem, the `name` key which prefixes its value to names.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing} 
\usegdlibrary {layered, trees}
\begin{document}
\tikz[>=stealth, auto]
\graph [
  layered layout, sibling distance=15mm, grow'=right,
  declare={myGraph}{a -> {1, 2}}
] {
  subA [draw, circle] // [tree layout] { myGraph[name=subA] };
  subB [draw, circle] // [tree layout] { myGraph[name=subB] };
  subA -> subB;
  subA a <->[red] subB 1;
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There's of course also the possibility to use different names but the same text for nodes, even just by using explicitly `aA/a -> {1A/1, 2A/2}` and `aB/a -> {1B/1, 2B/2}`.

Comment: my subgraphs are separated but the arrow linking two subgraphs is missing @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: another thing is, Tikz's been so hard for me to look for the properties I want, their document is ok, but it's hard to retrieve, any solution ?

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to use a variable to store a defined graph structure so I can reuse it when needed?

Comment: @Edee 1. The arrow is there, look closely between the circles. 2. I knew there's an `use existing nodes` key … there must be an opposite key for that, I thought. 3. There the [`declare` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/declare). At the end of that section is also an example that provides an alternative solution to your problem: `declare`. Let me update my answer.

Comment: another thing is, if I use 'fresh nodes' from outer layer, for the inside of each subgraph, it will always draw a new node, which is not my desire yet. To avoid it, I tried to use 'use existing nodes' for each subgraph, but it doesn't work so well. @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: and btw, your first code snippet does not work on my side. I was using lualatex, I make it work by adding bracket like (subA) -> (subB). How do you compile your code? Which one of us using outdated version? It's strange.

Comment: @Edee I'm using LuaLaTeX from an up-to-date TeXLive 2022.